# Issue related to serenity aggregate "net.thucydides.core.reports.TestOutcomes.getFailingOrErrorTests()Lnet/thucydides/core/reports/TestOutcomes""

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am new to Serenity- cucumber framework!

If anyone can help me in resolving the error in aggregate function in serenity. It would be very helpful for me to proceed further.

Error thrown is

```
"net.thucydides.core.reports.TestOutcomes.getFailingOrErrorTests()Lnet/thucydides/core/reports/TestOutcomes"
```

[image]

Comment: In pom.xml, you have 4 errors, please take screenshot for all of them.

Comment: I found this, it may help you https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/1673

Comment: Thank you lucasnguyen17! I have already tried with the link - it is not working for me

Comment: You need to provide more info, in your image, you have compile errors in your code.

Comment: lucasnguyen17 - Issue resolved, I  have reinstalled the cucumber plugin in intellij and issue got resolved